# Issues while aligning content after converting flash to html5

Tags: css, html, flash, html5-canvas

Earlier I uses a flash file inside tag to make it center on my Wordpress Website. But now since have converted into html5 so i can serve my content to android browser users. The problem is with aligning the content to center of the page for android browser. I need the fix so that the same code works for both Desktop browser and Android Browser.

Right now if you visit the website from your mobile [www.truckstopquebec.com](http://www.truckstopquebec.com) you will see that the half content goes out of the screen. I want to make it center align. I have tried several codes like max-width:100% height 200px; but the height goes wrong with large white content.

Can anyone suggest how do i fix this. I have used google swiffy to convert swf flash file into html5.

The Code which is needed to be styled is

```
  <div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 800px; height: 174px"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to canvases. Here is a site that I think should help you [center the div](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=center+div+css&t=ffab&ia=qa).

(You will learn a lot more through research than just getting the answer)